# How are the Laguerre polynomials and spherical harmonics related to the electronic quantum numbers?

Tags: quantum-chemistry

How are the [Laguerre polynomials](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laguerre_polynomials) and [spherical harmonics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spherical_harmonics) related to the quantum numbers $n, l, m_l$ of an electron in an atom?

Comment: http://www.astro.caltech.edu/~srk/Ay126/Lectures/Lecture3/SchrodingerModel.pdf

Comment: I'd write an answer, but busy today. In the meantime you might want to consult a physics text on the QM model of the hydrogen atom - most textbooks should devote a section to solving the Schrodinger equation, and should explain what the spherical harmonics and (associated) Laguerre polynomials are. Or someone else might answer, of course.

Comment: there is an answer to this question https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/80199/balmers-formula-and-lagurre-polynomials that covers most of the points asked here.